# wix windows 10 startmenu with multiple shortcuts

Tags: wix, windows-10, startmenu

so I have a msi that creates two startmenu folders. I want to put multiple shortcuts in the startmenu folder but on windows 10 it only puts the first shortcut. but if I use the same msi on a windows 7 build all the shortcuts are there. All the files that the shortcuts point to are in the install location.

I have googled all over and while there are many links on how to add start menu items. none address this windows 10 issue I'm having.
here is the code I have to add the items to the start menu.

```
<ComponentRef Id="CADDResources" />
<!--------------------------------------->
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)" />
    <Directory Id="CADDMenuFolder" Name="OhioDOT-CADD Resources"/>
  </Directory>
<!--------------------------------------->

<DirectoryRef Id="CADDMenuFolder">
      <Component Id="CADDResources" Guid="[YOURGUIDHERE]">
        <Shortcut Id="SupportRequest" Name="CADD Services - Request for Support" Description="Link to support request form" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]CADD Services - Request for Support.url" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <Shortcut Id="Youtubepage" Name="CADD Services - YouTube Channel.url" Description="Link to ODOT CADD's YouTube Channel" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]CADD Services - YouTube Channel.url" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <Shortcut Id="CADDMain" Name="CADD Services - Main.url" Description="Link to ODOT CADD's main webpage" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]CADD Services - Main.url" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <Shortcut Id="ODOTCommunities" Name="Bentley Communities - ODOT.url" Description="Link to ODOT CADD's Bentleys Communities page" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]Bentley Communities - ODOT.url" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFile Id="shourtcutfile1" Name="CADD Services - Request for Support.url" Directory="CADDMenuFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RemoveFile Id="shourtcutfile2" Name="CADD Services - YouTube Channel.url" Directory="CADDMenuFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RemoveFile Id="shourtcutfile3" Name="CADD Services - Main.url" Directory="CADDMenuFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RemoveFile Id="shourtcutfile4" Name="Bentley Communities - ODOT.url" Directory="CADDMenuFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="CleanUpShortCut2" Directory="CADDMenuFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\OhioDOT\CADD\Connect\OhioDOTCADDStandardsInstaller_Local" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
          <RegistryValue Name="Resources" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

I have also tried instead of putting all the shortcuts in one component, I made them all separate components and that did not work either. I'm at a loss at why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

well it took my posting this to see that I had .url at the end of the name for the shortcuts that were not showing up. removed that and then it worked.
must be some kind of restriction on windows 10 that doesn't allow that but in windows 7 it got by.

wish I would have noticed that earlier.

Comment: If you think your question is meaningless, you can delete it.